# how to resolve You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity, android-manifest

I have a SplashActivity which is showing an error `android.splash.ui.SplashActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.`

This started after I added a dependency `implementation ("com.github.espressif:esp-idf-provisioning-android:lib-2.1.2")`

Manifest for SplashActivity

```
<application
    android:name=".OApp"
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="${ClearTextEnabled}"
    android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
    tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">

    <!-- Activities -->
    <activity
        android:name=".splash.ui.SplashActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:exported="true"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter android:order="0">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="cpoints.opark.com"
                android:pathPattern="${DeepLinkBrand}"
                android:scheme="https" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

splash_acitivyt.xml looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".splash.ui.SplashActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <include layout="@layout/loading_view_white_bg"/>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Could you please suggest what I can do remove this error please

Thanks in advance
R

EDIT: as suggested by @Mikhail, I have added `Theme.AppCompat` as parent to `AppTheme.NoActionBar` but still have the same issue

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

SplashActivity - apologies I have given the full code for SplashActivity, just in case

```
package io.o.android.splash.ui

import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.SharedPreferences
import android.hardware.Sensor
import android.hardware.SensorEvent
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener
import android.hardware.SensorManager
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.viewModels
import androidx.annotation.IdRes
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
import androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
import androidx.fragment.app.commit
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import androidx.lifecycle.lifecycleScope
import com.firebase.ui.auth.AuthUI
import com.firebase.ui.auth.IdpResponse
import com.google.firebase.dynamiclinks.ktx.dynamicLinks
import com.google.firebase.ktx.Firebase
import com.stripe.android.CustomerSession
import com.uxcam.UXCam
import io.o.android.*
import io.o.android.BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE
import io.o.android.c.model.cBrand
import io.o.android.c.model.cId
import io.o.android.c.ui.cSignInActivity
import io.o.android.setup.ui.lDocumentsFragment
import io.o.android.setup.ui.lDocumentsFragmentHost
import io.o.android.setup.ui.WelcomeFragmentHost
import io.o.android.databinding.SplashActivityBinding
import io.o.android.fleet.ui.FleetIntroActivity
import io.o.android.getintouch.ui.GetInTouchActivity
import io.o.android.messaging.model.PushMessageType
import io.o.android.payments.model.PaymentSetupState
import io.o.android.publiccharging.ui.FinishChargingActivity
import io.o.android.repo.Resource
import io.o.android.repo.Resource.Status.*
import io.o.android.setup.model.SetupFlowType
import io.o.android.setup.model.SetupState
import io.o.android.setup.ui.SetupActivity
import io.o.android.setup.ui.WelcomeFragment
import io.o.android.splash.viewmodel.SplashViewModel
import io.o.android.subscription.ui.ManageSubscriptionsActivity
import io.o.android.theme.domain.ShowV2Look
import io.o.android.user.model.PendinglDocument
import io.o.android.user.model.UserAccountDB
import io.o.android.user.repo.UserRepository
import io.o.android.user.ui.DevAuthFragment
import io.o.android.util.*
import io.o.android.util.log.Logger
import io.o.android.util.network.EnvironmentKey
import io.o.android.util.network.HttpStatusCode.FORBIDDEN
import io.o.android.util.network.HttpStatusCode.UNAUTHORIZED
import io.o.android.util.ui.showErrorSnackbar
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import java.time.ZoneId
import javax.inject.Inject

class SplashActivity :
    FlowCheckingActivity(),
    DevAuthFragment.OnAuthListener,
    ForceUpdateFragment.OnActionListener,
    lDocumentsFragmentHost,
    WelcomeFragmentHost
{

    @Inject
    lateinit var authUI: AuthUI

    @Inject
    lateinit var app: oApp

    @Inject
    lateinit var viewModelFactory: ViewModelProvider.Factory
    private val viewModel: SplashViewModel by viewModels { viewModelFactory }

    @Inject
    lateinit var timeZoneId: ZoneId

    @Inject
    lateinit var sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences

    @Inject
    lateinit var userRepo: UserRepository

    @Inject
    lateinit var showV2Look: ShowV2Look

    private lateinit var binding: SplashActivityBinding
    override val toolbar: Toolbar?
        get() = null
    override val coordinatorLayout: CoordinatorLayout?
        get() = binding.coordinatorLayout

    private lateinit var userAccount: UserAccountDB

    // Extract from push notification
    private var loadedBundle: Bundle? = null
    private var pushType: PushMessageType? = null
    private var cBrand: cBrand? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        handleDeepLinkOpen()

        if (!isTaskRoot
            && intent.hasCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER)
            && intent.action != null
            && intent.action.equals(Intent.ACTION_MAIN)) {

            finish()
            return
        }

        // Only enable UXCam for prod
        if (SERVER == PRODUCTION) {
            UXCam.startWithKey(UXCAM_KEY)
        }

        binding = SplashActivityBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        // Check for reason of intent launch activity was opened
        intent.extras?.let {
            pushType = viewModel.processMessage(it)
            loadedBundle = it
        }

        viewModel.userAccount.observe(owner = this) { resource ->
            when (resource.status) {
                LOADING -> { /* DO NOTHING */ }
                SUCCESS -> {
                    userAccount = resource.data!!
                    checkMinValidAppVersion()
                }
                ERROR -> {
                    handleUserAccountError(resource.error)
                }
            }
        }

        val showAuthScreen = intent.getBooleanExtra(KEY_SHOW_AUTH_SCREEN, false)
        if (showAuthScreen) {
            // If the auth screens should be shown first then ignore the update of the user account and other steps
            showWelcomeScreen()
            return
        }

        // Only fetch the user config if the auth screen shouldn't be shown first
        fetchUserConfig()

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            showFragment(SplashFragment.newInstance())
        }
    }

    override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent?) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent)
        handleDeepLinkOpen()
    }
    
    private fun handleDeepLinkOpen() {
        Firebase.dynamicLinks.getDynamicLink(intent).addOnSuccessListener(this) { pendingDynamicLinkData ->
            // Get deep link from result (may be null if no link is found)
            if (pendingDynamicLinkData != null) {
                val deviceId = pendingDynamicLinkData.link?.getQueryParameter("id")
                deviceId?.let {
                    // Save a flag for the rest of the launch flow
                    viewModel.chargerDeviceId = if (TypeConfiguration.type == Type.PUBLIC) {
                        BrandConfiguration.CABLE_LINKING_PREFIX + it
                    } else {
                        it
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Fetch the configuration for the user.
     * This can consist of environment and feature availability.
     */
    private fun fetchUserConfig() {
        viewModel.getUserConfig().observe(owner = this) { resource ->
            when (resource.status) {
                LOADING -> { /* DO NOTHING */ }
                SUCCESS -> {
                    if (resource.data != null) {
                        if (resource.data.beta != null) {
                            processUserConfig(resource.data.beta!!)
                        } else {
                            viewModel.updateUserAccount(timeZoneId)
                        }
                    } else {
                        viewModel.updateUserAccount(timeZoneId)
                    }
                }
                ERROR -> {
                    handleUserAccountError(resource.error)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun processUserConfig(isBeta: Boolean) {
        val curEnv = viewModel.environment
        if (isBeta) {
            if (curEnv == EnvironmentKey.BETA) {
                viewModel.updateUserAccount(timeZoneId)
            } else {
                viewModel.environment = EnvironmentKey.BETA
                lifecycleScope.launch {
                    userRepo.clearLocalData()
                }

                showFragment(BetaWelcomeFragment.newInstance(EnvironmentKey.BETA))
            }
        } else {
            if (curEnv == EnvironmentKey.PRODUCTION) {
                viewModel.updateUserAccount(timeZoneId)
            } else {
                viewModel.environment = EnvironmentKey.PRODUCTION
                lifecycleScope.launch {
                    userRepo.clearLocalData()
                }

                showFragment(BetaWelcomeFragment.newInstance(EnvironmentKey.PRODUCTION))
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Gets the min valid app version from the [viewModel] and uses that and the [userAccount] info to decide which
     * screen should be shown next.
     */
    private fun checkMinValidAppVersion() {
        viewModel.getMinValidAppVersion().observe(owner = this) { resource ->
            when (resource.status) {
                LOADING -> { /* DO NOTHING */ }
                SUCCESS, ERROR -> {
                    // Continue even if we got an error, as we already have a default value in the app that will be
                    // returned when the backend value can't be fetched
                    val minValidAppVersion = resource.data!!
                    if (minValidAppVersion > VERSION_CODE) {
                        showFragment(ForceUpdateFragment.newInstance(userAccount.user.firstName))
                    } else {
                        showNextActivity()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun showNextActivity() {
        val curEnv = viewModel.environment
        val isUserBeta = curEnv == EnvironmentKey.BETA

        if (TypeConfiguration.type == Type.PUBLIC) {
            // Pre-initialise Stripe before sign in
            CustomerSession.initCustomerSession(applicationContext, viewModel.paymentRepo)
        }

        checkPendinglDocuments(isUserBeta)
    }

    private fun paymentNeedsSettingUp(elseContinue: () -> Unit) {
        val curEnv = viewModel.environment
        val isUserBeta = curEnv == EnvironmentKey.BETA
        viewModel.getUserSetupState().observe(owner = this) { resource ->
            when (resource.status) {
                LOADING -> { /* DO NOTHING */ }
                SUCCESS -> {
                    val state = resource.data ?: return@observe
                    if (TypeConfiguration.type == Type.PUBLIC) {
                        val paymentState = state.paymentAccounts[TypeConfiguration.PAYMENT_ACCOUNT_ID]?.accountSetupStatus ?: PaymentSetupState.NOT_STARTED
                        if (viewModel.chargerDeviceId.isNotEmpty() && paymentState == PaymentSetupState.NOT_STARTED) {
                            showActivity(SetupActivity.createIntent(this, SetupState.DEVICE_NOT_PROCESSED))
                        } else {
                            elseContinue()
                        }
                    } else if (TypeConfiguration.type == Type.HOME) {
                        if (userAccount.isSetupIncomplete(isUserBeta)) {
                            showActivity(FleetIntroActivity.createIntent(this, setupFlowType = SetupFlowType.CONNECT))
                        } else {
                            elseContinue()
                        }
                    }
                }
                ERROR -> {
                    elseContinue()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun showMainActivity() {
        viewModel.getChargeStatus().observe(owner = this) { resource ->
            when (resource.status) {
                LOADING -> { /* DO NOTHING */ }
                SUCCESS -> {
                    if (processPushMessage()) {
                        pushType = null
                        loadedBundle = null
                    } else {
                        if (showV2Look())
                            showActivity(Intent(this, SingleActivity::class.java))
                        else showActivity(MainActivity.createIntent(this, showV2Look))
                    }
                }
                ERROR -> {
                    showErrorSnackbar(id = SNACKBAR_ID_SESSION_FETCH_FAIL,
                            parent = binding.coordinatorLayout,
                            messageRes = R.string.splash_error_charge_status_fetch_failed,
                            actionBtnTextRes = R.string.snackbar_error_btn_retry,
                            onActionClick = { viewModel.updateChargeStatus() })
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun processPushMessage(): Boolean {
        when (pushType) {
            PushMessageType.SESSION_FINISHED -> {
                if (!showV2Look()) {
                    val sessionId = loadedBundle?.get("sessionId") as String?
                    sessionId?.let {
                        showActivity(FinishChargingActivity.createIntent(this, sessionId = it))
                        return true
                    } ?: run {
                        return false
                    }
                } else {
                    return false
                }
            }
            PushMessageType.USR_MSG_START_CHARGE_WITHOUT_SOC,
            PushMessageType.USR_MSG_SWITCH_TO_MAX_CHARGE_c_API -> {
                return if (!showV2Look()) {
                    val isAuthIssue = loadedBundle?.getString("authenticationIssue").toBoolean()
                    val cBrandId = loadedBundle?.getString("cBrand")

                    if (isAuthIssue && cBrandId != null) {
                        promptForcLogin(cBrandId)
                        true
                    } else {
                        false
                    }
                } else {
                    false
                }
            }
            PushMessageType.USR_MSG_c_API_FAIL -> {
                return if (!showV2Look()) {
                    val isAuthIssue = loadedBundle?.getString("authIssue").toBoolean()
                    val cBrandId = loadedBundle?.getString("cBrand")

                    if (isAuthIssue && cBrandId != null) {
                        promptForcLogin(cBrandId)
                        true
                    } else {
                        false
                    }
                } else {
                    false
                }
            }
            PushMessageType.USR_MSG_SUBSCRIPTION_PAST_DUE -> {
                return if (!showV2Look()) {
                    showActivity(ManageSubscriptionsActivity.createIntent(this, isModel = true))
                    true
                } else {
                    false
                }
            }
            else -> {
                return false
            }
        }
    }

    private fun promptForcLogin(cBrandId: String) {
        viewModel.getcBrand(cBrandId) { brand ->
            brand?.let {
                // Defend against further flow updates
                if (cBrand == null) {
                    cBrand = it
                    showActivity(cSignInActivity.createIntent(this, it))
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun handleUserAccountError(error: Resource.Error?) {
        when (error?.code) {
            UNAUTHORIZED, FORBIDDEN -> {
                showWelcomeScreen()
            }
            else -> {
                showErrorSnackbar(id = SNACKBAR_ID_ACCOUNT_FETCH_FAIL,
                        parent = binding.coordinatorLayout,
                        messageRes = R.string.splash_error_account_fetch_failed,
                        actionBtnTextRes = R.string.snackbar_error_btn_retry,
                        onActionClick = { fetchUserConfig() })
            }
        }
    }

    private fun getSetupStateAndProcess(userAccount: UserAccountDB) {

            viewModel.getUserSetupState().observe(this) { resource ->
                when (resource.status) {
                    LOADING -> {}
                    SUCCESS -> {
                        resource.data?.let { state ->
                            processSetupState(userAccount.isFleetUser,
                                userAccount.selectedFleet?.reimbursementSettlementType, state)
                        }
                    }
                    ERROR -> {
                        showErrorSnackbar(id = SNACKBAR_ID_ACCOUNT_FETCH_FAIL,
                            parent = binding.coordinatorLayout,
                            messageRes = R.string.splash_error_account_fetch_failed,
                            actionBtnTextRes = R.string.snackbar_error_btn_retry,
                            onActionClick = { getSetupStateAndProcess(userAccount) })
                    }
                }
            }
    }

    private fun checkPendinglDocuments(isUserBeta: Boolean) {
        viewModel.getUserSetupState().observe(this) { resource ->
            when (resource.status) {
                LOADING -> {}
                SUCCESS -> {
                    resource.data?.let { state ->
                       if(state.pendinglDocuments.isNotEmpty()) {
                           showlDocsFragment(state.pendinglDocuments, true, false)
                       } else {
                            checkSetupIncomplete(isUserBeta)
                       }
                    }
                }
                ERROR -> {
                    showErrorSnackbar(id = SNACKBAR_ID_ACCOUNT_FETCH_FAIL,
                        parent = binding.coordinatorLayout,
                        messageRes = R.string.splash_error_account_fetch_failed,
                        actionBtnTextRes = R.string.snackbar_error_btn_retry,
                        onActionClick = { checkPendinglDocuments(isUserBeta) })
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun checkSetupIncomplete(isUserBeta: Boolean) {
        if (userAccount.isSetupIncomplete(isUserBeta)) {
            getSetupStateAndProcess(userAccount)
        } else {
            paymentNeedsSettingUp(elseContinue = {
                userAccount.selectedc?.let { currentc ->


                    viewModel.getcCredentials(currentc, userAccount.user.id).observe(owner = this) { resource ->
                        when (resource.status) {
                            LOADING -> { /* DO NOTHING */ }
                            SUCCESS -> {
                                showMainActivity()
                            }
                            ERROR -> {
                                showActivity(cSignInActivity.createIntent(this))
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    }

    override fun showFragment(fragment: BaseFragment,
                              @IdRes containerViewId: Int,
                              replaceCurrent: Boolean,
                              addToBackStack: Boolean,
                              collapsingToolbarEnabled: Boolean) {
        // None of the fragments should be added to the back stack in the SplashActivity
        super.showFragment(fragment, containerViewId,
                replaceCurrent = true,
                addToBackStack = false,
                collapsingToolbarEnabled = true)

        hideLoadingView()
    }

    override fun onSignInSuccessful() {
        showLoadingView()
        fetchUserConfig()
    }

    override fun onSkipForceUpdate() {
        showNextActivity()
    }

    override fun onBackFromPlayStore() {
        checkMinValidAppVersion()
    }

    private fun showWelcomeScreen() {
        hideLoadingView()
        val fragment = WelcomeFragment()
        supportFragmentManager.commit {
            add(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment)
        }
    }

    private fun showlDocsFragment(
        pendinglDocuments: List<PendinglDocument>,
        loggedIn: Boolean,
        addToBackStack: Boolean) {
        val fragment = lDocumentsFragment.newInstance(pendinglDocuments, loggedIn)
        supportFragmentManager.commit {
            replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment)
            if (addToBackStack) addToBackStack(fragment.tag)
        }
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                onSignInSuccessful()
            } else {
                // do nothing
            }
        } else {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        }
    }

    // region Inner Types

    companion object : Logger() {

        private const val KEY_SHOW_AUTH_SCREEN = "show_auth_screen"

        /**
         * Ids for snackbar used to stop recreation of multiple of the same types if
         * snackbar.
         */
        private const val SNACKBAR_ID_SESSION_FETCH_FAIL = 0
        private const val SNACKBAR_ID_ACCOUNT_FETCH_FAIL = 1
        const val RC_SIGN_IN = 1

        /**
         * @param showAuthScreen `true` if the [DevAuthFragment] should be shown first in this `Activity`,
         * or `false` if the normal checks to decide which screen to show should occur.
         */
        fun createIntent(context: Context, showAuthScreen: Boolean = false): Intent {
            return Intent(context, SplashActivity::class.java).apply {
                putExtra(KEY_SHOW_AUTH_SCREEN, showAuthScreen)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onAgreelDocumentsComplete() {
        val curEnv = viewModel.environment
        val isUserBeta = curEnv == EnvironmentKey.BETA
        checkSetupIncomplete(isUserBeta)
    }

    override fun gotolDocumentsScreen(pendinglDocuments: List<PendinglDocument>) {
        showlDocsFragment(pendinglDocuments, false, true)
    }

    // endregion
}
```

FlowCheckingActivity

```
package io.o.android.splash.ui

import android.content.Intent
import io.o.android.dagger.ui.InjectionFragmentActivity
import io.o.android.setup.model.SetupState
import io.o.android.setup.ui.SetupActivity
import io.o.android.user.model.ReimbursementSettlement
import io.o.android.user.model.State
import io.o.android.user.model.UserSetupState
import io.o.android.util.Type
import io.o.android.util.TypeConfiguration
import io.o.android.util.ui.UIUtils.startActivityAndFinishOthers

abstract class FlowCheckingActivity: InjectionFragmentActivity() {

fun processSetupState(isfUser: Boolean, reimbursementSettlement: ReimbursementSettlement?, state: UserSetupState) {
if (TypeConfiguration.type == Type.PUBLIC) {
showActivity(SetupActivity.createIntent(this, SetupState.NONE))
} else if (TypeConfiguration.type == Type.HOME) {
val paymentSetupRequired = state.paymentAccountsToSetup?.any { it.gatewayId == TypeConfiguration.PAYMENT_ACCOUNT_ID }
 if (isfUser) {
if (state.personalDetails != State.COMPLETED &&
reimbursementSettlement == ReimbursementSettlement.BANK_TRANSFER) {
showActivity(SetupActivity.createIntent(this, SetupState.f_INTRO_REQUIRED))
} else if (state.personalDetails == State.COMPLETED &&
state.address != State.COMPLETED &&
reimbursementSettlement == ReimbursementSettlement.BANK_TRANSFER) {
showActivity(SetupActivity.createIntent(this, SetupState.ADDRESS_REQUIRED))
} else if (state.address != State.COMPLETED) {
showActivity(SetupActivity.createIntent(this, SetupState.f_INTRO_REQUIRED))
} else if (state.tariff != State.COMPLETED) {
showActivity(SetupActivity.createIntent(this, SetupState.TARIFF_REQUIRED))
} else if (state.utility != State.COMPLETED && reimbursementSettlement == ReimbursementSettlement.UTILITY) {
showActivity(SetupActivity.createIntent(this, SetupState.UTILITY_BILL_REQUIRED))
} else if (state.charger != State.COMPLETED) {
showActivity(SetupActivity.createIntent(this, SetupState.CHARGE_DEVICE_REQUIRED))
} else if (state.c != State.COMPLETED) {
showActivity(SetupActivity.createIntent(this, SetupState.c_LINK_REQUIRED))
}
} else if (state.address != State.COMPLETED) {
showActivity(SetupActivity.createIntent(this, SetupState.NONE))
} else if (state.charger != State.COMPLETED) {
showActivity(SetupActivity.createIntent(this, SetupState.CHARGE_DEVICE_REQUIRED))
} ce if (state.c != State.COMPLETED) {
showActivity(SetupActivity.createIntent(this, SetupState.c_LINcEQUIRED))
}
}
}

fun showActivity(intent: Intent) {
startActivityAndFinishOthers(intent)
}
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21814825/you-need-to-use-a-theme-appcompat-theme-or-descendant-with-this-activity)

Comment: I am using android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" for the whole application, does that need changing?

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems correctly. You haven't provided the code from your `styles.xml` file, so make sure that your `AppTheme.NoActionBar` style inherits from `Theme.AppCompat`. It should look something like this:

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <!-- Your attributes -->
</style>
```

Comment: Thank you @Mikhail for coming back, styles.xml looks like this 
 <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
  <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
  <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
 </style>
ok will add the parent and check how it goes, thank you so much

Comment: Hello, update: I tried that, but still had the same issue, anything else you can think off please?

Comment: Can you provide the code of your Activity as well?

Comment: I have added the SplashActivity thank you

Comment: Thanks. What is FlowCheckingActivity?

Comment: thank you for helping, I have edited the question with FlowCheckingActivity

Comment: I need the code InjectionFragmentActivity as well. Basically, every ancestor until AppCompatActivity class from Android SDK

Comment: And can you format it properly please?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256078/discussion-between-brdroid-and-mikhail-guliaev).

Comment: I have added rest of the files in the char @Mikhail, thank you for your assistance